# CSS scale from left top

Tags: html, css, scale

I am trying to scale my entire page from the top left. This is what my original page looks like:

[image]

However when I try to scale my page, this happens:

[image]

This is my CSS:

```
html {
    zoom: 1.4; /* Old IE only */
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    transform: scale(1.4);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It cuts off part of my page.

Comment: can you post your html code please?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42705761/knkvp.html

Comment: Can't understand what's wrong..

Comment: Just a notice: Zooming and scaling are not the same. In chrome for example your code will zoom **and** scale. So it's not *old IE only*

Answer (score 58):

I was able to "solve" my problem.

This is what I tried:

- In the CSS shown in the question, I changed `html` to `body`:

  ```
  body {
      zoom: 1.4; /* Old IE only */
      -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
      transform: scale(1.4);
      transform-origin: top center;
      margin-top: 5px;
  }
  ```
- I  changed `transform-origin: top left` to `transform-origin: top
  center`.
- I also changed the CSS of my container div so that it is centered.

This fixed the problem partly as it centered to page nicely.

However, part of the top page still isn't displayed correctly. To fix this I added a `margin-top` to my `body`.

Answer (score 32):

I know this question is 3 years old but I just stumbled on it. The reason your transform is not positioned correctly is because your transform-origin parameters are backwards and thus are ignored. It's "transform-origin: x-axis y-axis" so you should have "transform-origin: left top", not "transform-origin: top left".

Comment: I always had trouble myself remembering which was X and which was Y. A teacher gave me a _mnemonic device_ that helped me: **X to the left, Y to the sky**. It's pretty standard, if not technically-standard that anything that wants orientation or coordinates will want it in `X,Y` format.

Comment: This answer does solve the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 zoom: 1.4; 
-moz-transform: scale(1.4);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
```

Scaling is cutting off your content. Reduce scaling to 0.4, it's rendering properly.

```
zoom: 0.4; 
-moz-transform: scale(0.4);
-webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
```

Comment: zoom is nonstandard CSS property and does not be recommended in production use

Answer (score 0):

for some reason, my browser seems to ignore `transform-origin` for particular elements such as `iframe`, therefore, in order to transform by `left top`, I wrote them all in `transform` property;

```css
transform: scale(0.5) translate(-50%, -50%);
```